# Debug watch not showing value: An object reference is required for the non-static field

Tags: axapta, dynamics-365-operations

I have a form, in VS code editor, I declare an amount type right in the beginning with below code

"Amount  X;"

Then in its Datasource, in method validateWrite(),

I have a line  "X = element.aFunction();"

When I debug to the line above and try to add a watch to the value of X the debugger says "error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property".

Any way to let me see its value?

Comment: Please let me know where you are declaring? Also it will be good if you put screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted an answer to this question elsewhere:

"Add "element" to watch and expand it. THere you should be able to see "X" and its value."